# How do you save session in texmaker to preserve master mode?

Tags: texmaker

I have to define every time that the main document is in master mode. I can't find a "save session" in my file menu. Is there a auto save session/auto restore saved session?

I run latest texmaker on latest Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

In Texmaker 3.3.4 (Latest version-May 24 2012), its possible to save the current session in .tks (texmaker session) format. Once you click the current document as  'Master document', just save the whole . tex files as one session as shown below.

[image]

if the latest version is not available in Ubuntu Software Repository/synaptic manager, try downloading a .deb/.rpm made for your linux distro at
http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux

Inorder to Install the .deb you need a gdebi package installer available in Ubuntu Software Repository

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the solution you wanted, but try [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/). It’s the *bigger brother* of TeXmaker and saves your session automatically. Maybe you must activate this feature (see below).

Here’s an image from the german Mac OS X version:

[image: TeXstudio]